# Dart-Sass not being added to PATH

Tags: sass, path, dart-sass

So, I've downloaded the [.zip 1.32.11 Windows x64 release from the Dart-Sass's Github repo](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/download/1.32.11/dart-sass-1.32.11-windows-x64.zip) and extracted it to the Program Files folder. Using the [steps](https://katiek2.github.io/path-doc/) provided, I found `Path` under `System variables` in Step 4. There was no `PATH` there, the closest thing was `PATHTEXT` and `Path`. My first question: Can I use `Path` or I have to create a new System variable called `PATH`. Thinking `Path` was sufficient, I decided to edit the System variable and then press Browse to search for the Dart-Sass folder. After this was done, I went to Command Prompt and typed `sass -version`. The result was that Sass was not recognized. Did I do anything wrong? If so, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing two things about your problem. The first is your path variable... did you make sure to change `Me` to your username in the `PATH` variable?. The second encompasses your installation. Can you find the dart `*.exe` file? If not, try uninstalling and reinstalling, making sure each step is completed word for word.

Comment: For the first thing, I just went to the Sass folder when I was editing the `Path` System library using the Browse button on the side which allowed me to browse through my files and find it which was easy. I don't know if that was the right thing to do. For the second thing, Yes, I can see the file with this path: `the folder housing Dart-Sass Program Files > dart-sass > src > dart.exe`.

Comment: @SriyansKanneganti Check the absolute path to `dart.exe` and make sure that the containing folder (not the exact executable) is in your `path` variable. If this doesn't work, I'm very sorry as I do not use windows and cannot sufficiently answer your question

Comment: @SriyansKanneganti You can check this by opening the command prompt in the directory of `dart.exe` and issuing `pwd` to get your _present_ _working_ _directory_.

Comment: Holy shoot nvm. I might've accidentally added the wrong folder to the path as I readded it today and it worked. Thanks for your help!